# Running commands in an azure VM from Azure devops

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have got the following code as a task in Azure devops, the task finishes ok but notepad isnt runining on the target vm? It doesnt seem to have worked any ideas?

## script.ps1

## start-process notepad.exe

az --% vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name vmname -g $ rgname --scripts '@script.ps1'

Answer (score 0):

Add 'get-process' to your script.ps1 so it now becomes

```
start-process notepad.exe;get-process
```

You should be able to see notepad.exe in the get-process output. This happens because azure creates a new session to run the 'invoke command' and when the execution is concluded, the session is terminated. The session you're logged into is a different one.

Comment: how can i get it to run as a specific user?

Comment: It's not the problem of the user, buddy.
az cli already runs it with Admin credentials. Windows security model prevents you from doing it. You could be using the same account with the same credentials but you will still be served different sessions.
Read this answer for further clarifications
https://serverfault.com/questions/690852/use-powershell-to-start-a-gui-program-on-a-remote-machine/852877

Comment: However, you can stop the processes across sessions. So if you open a notepad instance and change your script.ps1 code to "Stop-Process -Name notepad", you should be able to see the notepad window close in your session as well.